# "Load More" pagination button works but jumps to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a "Load More" button at the bottom of my page which works but when used the page jumps to the top. How can I keep the browser in place?

Here's my code.

```
        <div class="product-list__pagination">
            <ul class="justify-content-center" style="padding-left:0px;">
                @if($items->lastPage() != $items->currentPage())
                    <a href="#" onclick="loadMore()" class="btn btn-primary" id="load-more-btn">
                        <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse d-none" id="load-more-loading"></i> Load More
                    </a>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Below is the JS script.

```
<script>
        var _nextPage = 1;
        function loadMore() {
            _nextPage++;
            let url = new URL(window.location.href);
            url.searchParams.set('page', _nextPage);

            $.ajax({
                url: url.href,
                datatype: "html",
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#load-more-loading').removeClass('d-none');
                }
            })
                .done(function (response) {
                    if (response.length == 0) {
                        $('#load-more-btn').hide();
                        return;
                    }
                    $('#load-more-loading').addClass('d-none');
                    $("#load-more-container").append(response);
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log('Server error occured');
                    $('#load-more-loading').addClass('d-none');
                    $('#load-more-btn').hide();
                });
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `href="javascript:void(0);"`

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadMore()"
```